# makefile computing diff fails

Tags: makefile, diff

When I try to compute the `diff` between two text files:

```
results.txt: file1.txt file2.txt
    diff $(word 1,$^) $(word 2,$^) > $@
```

I get this weird (?) error:

```
$ make
diff file1.txt file2.txt > results.txt
makefile:2: recipe for target 'results.txt' failed
make: *** [results.txt] Error 1
```

What's wrong with my makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `diff` typically has a non-zero exit code if the files differ.  This will cause `make` to infer the command failed.  The easy fix would be to tell `make` to [ignore the exit code](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors)...

```
results.txt: file1.txt file2.txt
    -diff $(word 1,$^) $(word 2,$^) > $@
```

**Edit:** If the aim is to get rid of the diagnostic message entirely then you could just use something like...

```
results.txt: file1.txt file2.txt
    diff $(word 1,$^) $(word 2,$^) > $@ || exit 0
```

Comment: Any way to remove the ugly `make: [results.txt] Error 1 (ignored)` as well?